# How to get context in opencv ocl?

Tags: c++, opencv, ocl

I am trying to run my first program using `OpenCV::ocl` without success. I have an exception when calling `cv::ocl::Context::getContext()`:

```
#include <opencv2/ocl/ocl.hpp>
#include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/ocl.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/gpu.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::ocl::Context *context_ocl;
    try{
        context_ocl = cv::ocl::Context::getContext();
    }
    catch (cv::Exception e){
        std::cout << e.msg << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...){
        std::cout << "Exception" << std::endl;
    }
    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The try-catch statement cannot catch the exception, so I don't know where is the problem.

I used to use OpenCV without issues, so I think it's built properly. Here is my linker input:
[image: my list of .lib]

Comment: I use OpenCV 2.4.11

Comment: What error do you get? In OpenCV v2.4.13 and v3.3.1, I use `context_ocl = &ocl::Context::getDefault();`.

Comment: I get an `Unhandled exception at 0xBAADF00D in myApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xBAADF00D`

Comment: Another thing, when I try to declare a `PlatformInfo` like this: `cv::ocl::PlatformInfo platformInfo;` I get `error LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol ... cv::ocl::PlatformInfo::~PlatformInfo(void)`